# Pigeon hole principle based puzzle question

Tags: puzzle, pigeonhole-principle

A card-board box contains 12 pairs each of three different types of hand gloves used by batsman in cricket. They are separated into single units of gloves and all mixed. you can not see the gloves from outside, but you can put your hands through the pigeon hole and takeout one glove at a time. what will be the minimum number of gloves one should take out to get one perfect pair of gloves to be sure?

I'm not sure how the answer is 13.
Firstly, I think no of gloves are 24 since 12 pairs are there. 
Now, to definitely make sure that we get a pair out, on the 1st attempt we take out 1 glove (23 gloves remain) and then on the next 22 attempts, I take out other gloves of different type (my assumption here is that the 1st glove I picked is of the type of which there are only 1 pair present) which would not match the glove I have already taken out. Now, on the next attempt 24th I will definitely take out the glove I want. Please explain why am I wrong here. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the answer's $13$?

Comment: @EpicGuy: I thought the same initially, that there are 36 pairs but I checked 2-3 sources everywhere the answer given is 13, but still I am not sure whether the question is saying that there are 12 pairs in all or as you say 36 pairs. Probably, I saw the answer as 13 and was looking to fill the answer myself.

Comment: Ok I was just checking you didn't get the answer from a friend or something. The way it's worded suggests there are $36$ pairs, but I will keep my answer deleted for now.

Comment: If you deleted *each* then it'd make the situation different.

Comment: 12 pairs each of three different types --- that's 36 pairs, for sure. Does "pairs" mean left gloves are different from right gloves, and you need one of each to make a pair?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes you are right that "left gloves are different from right gloves, and you need one of each to make a pair". But I think the question still says that there are only 12 pairs, not 36 as I also thought initially. Thanks !!

Comment: The question is worded poorly: "12 pairs each of 3 different types of gloves" is $36$ pairs.  "12 pairs of gloves, of 3 different types" is $12$ pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is

```
will be the minimum number of gloves one should take out to get one perfect 
pair of gloves **to be sure?**
```

To "be sure" you have to account for the worst case scenario, which is that (however unlikely it is) you extract all (for example) right handed gloves first.
Then you are sure that the next glove will be a left one, and will match any of the right gloves you have already extracted.

Since there are 12 pairs, the worst case scenario is that you extract 12 right hand gloves first. And then you are sure that the next one is going to be a left one, which will match one of the right handed gloves you have extracted first (because you have extracted all of them).

Any other scenario involves extracting less gloves, so 13 is the *minimum to be sure*.

> but the problem states that there are 3 different
>   kinds of gloves lets says a) the ones which right-handed batsman use,
>   b) the ones which left handed batsmen use and c) the wicket-keeping
>   gloves. Now, I can not be sure that after 12 gloves I would get the
>   same pair because there are 3 pairs and that too their nos are not
>   given. For ex- there might be 10 right-handed pairs of gloves, 1
>   left-handed pair of gloves and 1 keeping pair of gloves and I I happen
>   to pick one of the keeping glove, the worst case now becomes picking
>   20+2=22 more attempts ?? –

In your example, there are 10 pairs of right-handed pairs of gloves, 1 left-handed pair and 1 keeping pair. In the worst case scenario, you pick for example 12 right hand gloves (10 right hands from the right-handed pairs, 1 right hand from the left-handed pair and 1 right hand from the keeper pair). Now the 13th glove must be a left hand glove, because there are no right hand gloves in the card-board box. It is either a left hand glove from one of the 10 right hand sets, the left hand glove from the left-handed set or the left hand glove from the keeper set.

Comment: Thanks !! I get it, but the problem states that there are 3 different kinds of gloves lets says a) the ones which right-handed batsman use, b) the ones which left handed batsmen use and c) the wicket-keeping gloves. Now, I can not be sure that after 12 gloves I would get the same pair because there are 3 pairs and that too their nos are not given. For ex- there might be 10 right-handed pairs of gloves, 1 left-handed pair of gloves and 1 keeping pair of gloves and I I happen to pick one of the keeping glove, the worst case now becomes picking 20+2=22 more attempts ??

Comment: Seems correct but again the question says "one perfect pair of gloves to be sure", what does perfect pair mean ? Does perfect mean that if we pick lets say a right-handed glove from right-hander's pair on the 1st attempt, and then on the next 11 attempts we pick 10 right-hander glove from right-hander's pair and right glove from keeper's pair and finally on the 13th attempt we pick either the keeper's pair or left-hander pair or the right-hander pair, it is going to match any one pair definitely. Thank you very much !! Perfect !! Figured out while writing the comment :P.

Comment: "Any other scenario involves extracting less gloves, so 13 is the $minimum to be sure$."  This makes it sound like there are no other scenarios where you need $13$ gloves, which isn't true.  You don't need the first $12$ gloves to all have the same handedness, so I think this part deserves a little more justification.

Answer (score 1):

since there are 12 pairs of gloves it means that there are 12 left gloves and 12 right gloves.
even if the probability is low, it is still possible to pick 12 left on your first 12 picks. therefore on your 13th pick you are sure to pick a right glove giving you a complete pair of any of the three types og gloves
same goes if you picked first all right gloves in your first 12 picks.

Answer (score 1):

According to me answer is 37.

- 12 pair i.e 24 pieces (first type glove). Worst case is when 12
  pieces are selected of any one hand.That may be right or left.
- 12 pair i.e 24 pieces (second type glove). Same 12 are selected.
- 12 pair i.e 24 pieces (third type glove). Same 12 are selected.

$12+12+12+1=37$, where the last that makes the pair.